# What are these things called on a sliding door?

Tags: sliding-glass-door

I have these sliding doors and the guides that prevent the door from moving/rotating when sliding are missing. Does anyone know what they are called?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For my sliding doors, they are the upper guides.

However different manufacturers may have different terminology.

My local big box stores have some parts for a few sliding doors, but admittedly it's a shot in the dark.
Your best bet is to call the manufacturer if you need a replacement part. You could also call a sliding door service company. They will be more likely to have seen a number of manufacturers and can get or may have the part.

Comment: They are track covers to reduce air from coming through the top of the door where the doors interlock and underneath the track. There should be a corresponding one on the rolling panel as well.